# Outlook Calendar: Turn Color Categories into Calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

A friend wants to switch from using color categories in Outlook 2007 to using separate calendars. There are only a handful of events in their calendar that have multiple categories, and those should simply be copied to multiple calendars.

After trying to find a way to turn categories into separate calendars I have come up empty; I could not find a way to either...

- export only those events with a certain color category, (to then import them into a new calendar), or...
- to export *everything* (categories are retained in ical files) and then apply a color category filter upon re-importing the ical file into a new calendar.

I also tried to do the import/export from Thunderbird and Google Calendar.
What tool/set of steps can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Outlook also offers to export all events of one calendar in CSV format. Such a file can then be filtered by category, and the remaining contents can easily be imported into a new calendar.